# Cross-compiler vs JVM

Tags: java, cross-compiling

I am wondering about the purpose of JVM. If JVM was created to allow platform independent executable code, then can't a cross-compiler which is capable of producing platform independent executable code replace a JVM?

the information about cross-compiler was retrieved from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, and how. Cross- compilers mean compilation. Bytecode doesn't require additional compilation. Java includes OS hooks, including GUI functionality; you need to compile (again) and use a cross-platform GUI library if you're not using Java.

Comment: Pray tell, what would this platform independent executable code look like and how would it run on all platforms without a JVM analogue?

Comment: The JVM had a "pre-cursor", it was called [p-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-code_machine). Microsoft's Common Language Runtime is another "platform independent" executable code.

Comment: If you could compile your application to each target environment, you would need to include the required library binaries for each platform, which could take your nice little app from several kilo bytes, to 10s of mega bytes (if I recall, the JVM is something like 30mb). So, instead of being able to deploy a single Jar (or bundles) of fraction the size, you'd now need to included a executable for each platform. You'd probably also need the each environment you want to compile to so that the required libraries could be linked in...more complications...

Comment: You are misunderstanding what cross compiler does. It produces output for other system than where it is run, binary which can not run on same machine (except with emulator). Cross-compiling has nothing to do with platform independent code.

Answer (score 3):

The advantage of the bytecode format and the JVM is the ability to optimize code at runtime, based on profiling data acquired during the actual run. In other words, not having statically compiled native code is a *win*.

A specifically interesting example of the advantages of runtime compilation are *monomorphic call sites*: for each place in code where an instance method is being called, the runtime keeps track exactly what object types the method is called on. In very many cases it will turn out that there is only one object type involved and the JVM will then compile that call is if it was a static method (no *vtables* involved). This will further allow it to *inline* the call and then do even more optimizations such as escape analysis, register allocation, constant folding, and much more.

In fact, your criticism could (some say, *should*) be turned upside-down: why does Java define bytecode at all, fixing many design decisions which could have been left up to the implementation? The modern trend is to distribute *source code* and have the JIT compiler work on that.

Answer (score 1):

JVM is doing much more than compiling. JVM is an interpreter for byte code, which also contain  JIT (just in time) compiler that compiles byte code - but depending on the context of the application the same byte code can be compiled differently based on the runtime context (it decides in the runtime how your byte code is compiled). JIT is doing lof of optimization - it is trying to compile your code in most efficient way. Cross compiler can't do (all of) this because it doesn't know how your code will be used in the runtime. This is the big advantage of JVM over cross compiler.

I haven't been using cross compiler before but I guess that the advantage of crosscompiler is that you have better control on how your code is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

> platform independent executable code

That's what Java bytecode is. The problem with "platform independent executable code" is that it can't be native to every platform (otherwise being platform independent would be a trivial, uninteresting property). In other words, there is no format which runs without natively on all platforms.
The JVM is, depending on your definition of the term, either the ISA which defines Java bytecode, or the component that allows Java bytecode to be run on platforms whose native format for executable code isn't Java bytecode.

Of course, there is an infinite design space for alternative platform independent executable code and the above is true for any other occupant of said space. So yes, in a sense you can replace the JVM with another thing which fulfills the same function for another platform independent executable code format.